# Can I save an NSUserDefault value based on another NSUserDefault value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
I've location saved in NSUserDefaults. Now with this added in NSUserDefault user will select a value and I want to save this value in for this location. So when user selects that location again I can get the selected location back.
So this value is different for different locations and user can also change them at anytime. i want to know is it possible to do so? If not then what will be the optimized way to do this? I haven't started this implementation yet so there is no code.

Comment: you save the value on key-value basis. IF the key is same , then the value will be over writern everytme you save the value. If the key is diifferent, then you need a way to track all those keys!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a dictionary:

```
let dict:[String:String] = ["key":"value"]
// set multiple values into a specific location
UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "locationA")

// get the values for a given location
let result = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "locationA")
print(result!)
```

or a simple value

```
let value = "value"

// set simple value into a specific location (for key)
UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "locationA")

// get the value for a given location
let result = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "locationA")
print(result!)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this. For each location you could create a two-item `NSArray` in which the first item is the location, and the second item is the value. For example:

```
NSArray *locationData = @[location, value];
```

You would keep an `NSArray` of those two-item `NSArrays`, and save that to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSArray *allLocations = @[@[location1, value1], @[location2, value2], ...];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:allLocations forKey:@"LocationData"];
```

To look up the value for a particular location you would walk through the array (this code considers any location within 100m to be the same location):

```
- (id)valueForLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    for (NSArray *locInfo in allLocations) {
        CLLocation *loc = (CLLocation *) locInfo[0];
        if ([location distanceFromLocation:loc] < 100) {
            return locInfo[1];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Another way to do this is to store this information in a dictionary, keyed off the location. You can't use a `CLLocation` as a key directly, but you put a `CLLocation`'s coordinates into an `NSValue` and use that. For more details see [using CLLocation objects as keys in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771508/using-cllocation-objects-as-keys-in-dictionary).